# Are there any open access databases of all (or close enough) academic papers ever published? (not full-text)

Tags: research-process, databases

Was wondering if there were any reasonably exhaustive open databases listing academic papers, with just the preliminary info, namely Title, authors, journal, etc. with or without abstract. I'm not looking for full-texts here.

Comment: Did you check Google Scholar? For CS (and EE?), DBLP is close to exhaustiveness.

Comment: What does "open" mean for you?  Free to query, or free to download the entire data set?

Comment: "Academic paper ever published" is a pretty ambitious and vague goal. What time frame are we taking about? University journals, published conference abstracts, thesises also included?

Comment: Try [BASE](https://www.base-search.net) (you can switch to English and select "only OA" for Browsing) or [oaDOI](https://oadoi.org).

Comment: @NateEldredge, free to download entire dataset.

Comment: @qsp I would like to see the entire dataset rather than querying. So google scholar wouldn't work.

Comment: Well, there is [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data), though it's preprints instead of papers, and limited to a few fields over the relatively recent past.  I don't know of anything like this for published papers.  This data is not easy to gather, and the organizations that have done it don't give it away.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean databases that are free to query so that you get to see all metadata stored without any subscription (i.e., not Scopus or Web of Science)?

Yes, there are various free platforms of that kind. My favourite (cross-disciplinary) ones are:

- [LENS.org](https://www.lens.org/) (my favourite one - very comprehensive, and allows additional analyses and visualisations)
- [Microsoft Academic](https://academic.microsoft.com/) (not bad, powered by a semantic search approach)
- [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/) (probably the most prominent one)
- [Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/) (another semantic search approach)
- [ScienceOpen](https://www.scienceopen.com/) (not too familiar with it)
- [CrossRef Search](http://search.crossref.org/) (only offers metadata about articles that have a DOI registered at CrossRef)
- [Wizdom.ai](https://www.wizdom.ai/) (offers interesting analyses, e.g. regarding research trends and grants)