# How to export search results from Elsevier?

Tags: software, literature-search, tools, elsevier

I am doing a systematic review and I am cataloging my searches.
I've already exported the search results from IEEE, and from Springer, with one click to an CSV file.

So I wonder how to do the same thing with the Elsevier site `https://www.elsevier.com/search-results`

In the IEEE site I've just clicked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgxSr.png) and saved the CSV file. Same in the [Springer site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/031Ud.png).

Does anyone know how I can download from [Elsevier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkfJ1.png)?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean Scopus?

If you have your results page, there is a grey horizontal menu bar on the top of the search results. It contains the link "CSV export". This is where you have to click on, then you can select the metadata you wish to download.

Make sure to first select the documents, perhaps the box "All" left to "CSV export", before the link "CSV export" becomes clickable.

See an example here:

[image: Search result from Scopus]

Comment: This site is the same that I've post ? This sidebar is not appearing for me.

Comment: Oh - I thought you were talking about *Scopus*. In the Elsevier search you linked to, I do not see any possibility to export the results. - - Just to make sure: The Elsevier search does not show any papers, but only results pertaining to Elsevier's website, books and journals (not on paper-level). Is this really what you want? Because if you want to have data about papers, then you would need to use Scopus (which belongs to Elsevier).

Comment: So how do I do that in Scopus ? I've just found the journals and their H-index and all this metrics, but not the metadata from the list of the search. Thanks again

Comment: Does https://www.scopus.com/ work for you? If you cannot get search results like that, then you might need to ask your university library if they have a Scopus subscription. (And if they do not have a Scopus subscription, you could use [alternative and free databases](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/87482/are-there-any-open-access-databases-of-all-or-close-enough-academic-papers-eve/161455#161455)...)